# Why is for(;;) used?

Tags: c, for-loop

I have seen code (in C) which contains something similar to:

```
for(;;){
}
```

How would this work, and why is it used in any instance?

Comment: To loop forever. Or until something breaks out of the loop.

Comment: It's `for` nothing.

Comment: This was used instead of `while(TRUE)` because (from what I hear) there were issues with the portability of TRUE. Some systems defined TRUE and FALSE with different underlying values. I have no idea if that is true in practice.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Shouldn't it be for everything?  For nothing would be a loop with no iterations, I'd expect.

Comment: This is definitely a dupe, but I'm surprised no one's mentioned the compiler warning side of things.

Comment: @vcsjones: Some compilers (notably VC) used to warn about `while(true)` because the expression is constant. That's why in one shop I used to work, the guideline was to use `for(;;)` instead.

Comment: @chris: I was typing the very thing while you wondered, and hit the enter key only 6secs after you did... `:)`

Comment: @vcsjones historically some early UNIX compilers would generate a test for `while(1)`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is the idiomatic way to have an infinite loop.

In the C Programming Language book, by Kernighan & Ritchie book it was introduced in section 3.5:

```
for (;;) {
    ...
 }
```

> is an *infinite* loop, presumably to be broken by other means, such as a break or return.

Comment: I don't know if I'd say it's the idiomatic way...it's certainly *a* way.

Comment: looks like idiomatic C to me.

Comment: Just check the C Programming Language book and it is the idiomatic way.

Answer (score 8):

is an infinite loop  something like

```
while(true) 
{}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is equivalent to an infinite loop, as many other have explained. However, few of them explained *why* this executes as an infinite loop.

A `for` loop can be broken down into three parts:

```
for(initialization(s); condition(s); looping command(s))
```

None of these fields are actually required. Without a condition provided, there's nothing to stop the command from running. This is because the `for` loop looks for a **false** statement. Without conditions provided, nothing is false, therefore the loop runs indefinitely.

Therefore to cause a `for` loop to be infinite, all you need is to not provide a condition. This means that this is also a valid infinite loop:

```
for(int i = 0;; i++)
    printf("Iteration: %i\n", i);
```

For readability, and to make sure that the second semi-colon isn't a typo, some programmers might put a space between them, or put `true` as the condition.

Honestly, I prefer `while(true)`, as this is a clear infinite loop. Using `while(1)` works as well, but '1' is an integer, not a boolean. While it is equivalent to `true`, it does not always mean `true`.

Between these three types of infinite loops, `for(;;)` has the fewest characters (7). `while(1)` comes second at 8 characters, and `while(true)` at 11.

I suppose that certain programmers prefer a low byte count over a readable program, but I wouldn't recommend using `for(;;)`. While equivalent, I believe that using `while(true)` is better practice.

Answer (score 5):

A `for` loop needs three expressions, which are separated by semicolons, and are completely optional:

- An initialization (e.g. `int i=0`)
- A condition (e.g. `i < 10`)
- An afterthought (e.g. `i++`)

In this case, the three expressions are empty, and thus there's no condition that will make the loop stop, thus creating an infinite loop, unless a flow control instruction like `break` (which will exit the loop) or `return` is used.

Answer (score 4):

Its an infinite loop. Its equivalent to:

```
while (true) {
}
```

The C# compiler directly translates `for (; ;)` into the exact same construct as `while (true)`.

Answer (score 4):

**Infinite loop**

same as

```
while(true){}
```

Answer (score 4):

the code `for(;;){}` or `while(true){}` or `while(1){}` all represent infinite loops. 
An infinite loop is something to be expected in a software system that is expected to run and "unlimited" amount of time. Every OS has at least one - it's how a background task or idle task is implemented.

Real Time systems use infinite loops as well  because the system has to handle events which are asynchronous;

Basically anything that runs software uses infinite loops in one way or another.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why no one answered *why* people do this instead of `while(true)`: It's because `while(true)` will often generate a compilation warning that the condition of the loop is constant.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of infinite loop can be used in microcontroleurs. In your main function, you initialize the basic functions of your microcontroleur, then put a `while (1)`.

```
void MAIN(void)
{
  Init_Device();
  while(1);
}
```

The microcontroleur will then do nothing but wait for interrupts of internal or external devices (like a timer overflow, or UART data ready to be read), and react to these interrupts.